Issue loading files from dependency cache for yocto build
I am attempting to build a yocto build for the imx8 for the first time.
I have set up a docker file from the following github (I believe the official imx8 branch), and am building from this branch:
https://github.com/compulab-yokneam/yocker
https://github.com/compulab-yokneam/meta-bsp-imx8mp/tree/som-imx8m-plus-r2.0?tab=readme-ov-file
I am trying to build it within a Docker build on windows (using WSL2).
When I build it the first time, I get the following data:
Loading cache: 100% |                           | ETA:  --:--:--
Loaded 0 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |##########################| Time: 0:08:09
Parsing of 3233 .bb files complete (0 cached, 3233 parsed). 4784 targets, 266 skipped, 20 masked, 0 errors.

Basically nothing gets loaded from the cache, and we spend about 10 min parsing recipes. Building the whole image takes a significant amount of time, and I am trying to optimise that (but that is a separate problem).
If I try and rebuild, it  loads files from the dependency cache but then hangs.
I've left it for 20 minutes before rebooting it. This is where it hangs:
Loading cache: 100% |############################| Time: 0:00:02
Loaded 4779 entries from dependency cache.


DEBUG: Using cache in '/work/compulab-imx8p-som/build-som-imx8m-plus/cache/bb_unihashes.dat'

DEBUG: Processing core in collection list

DEBUG: Processing yocto in collection list

DEBUG: Processing openembedded-layer in collection list

DEBUG: Processing multimedia-layer in collection list

DEBUG: Processing meta-python in collection list

DEBUG: Processing freescale-layer in collection list

DEBUG: Processing freescale-3rdparty in collection list

DEBUG: Processing freescale-distro in collection list

DEBUG: Processing fsl-bsp-release in collection list

DEBUG: Processing fsl-sdk-release in collection list

DEBUG: Processing meta-ml in collection list

DEBUG: Processing v2x-imx in collection list

DEBUG: Processing imx-demo in collection list

DEBUG: Processing chromium-browser-layer in collection list

DEBUG: Processing clang-layer in collection list

DEBUG: Processing gnome-layer in collection list

DEBUG: Processing networking-layer in collection list

DEBUG: Processing filesystems-layer in collection list

DEBUG: Processing qt6-layer in collection list

DEBUG: Processing virtualization-layer in collection list

DEBUG: Processing compulab-bsp-imx8mp in collection list

DEBUG: Processing compulab in collection list

DEBUG: Processing compulab-desktop in collection list

DEBUG: Processing compulab-multimedia in collection list

DEBUG: Processing compulab-graphics in collection list

DEBUG: Processing compulab-utils in collection list

DEBUG: Processing compulab-bsp in collection list

DEBUG: Processing compulab-devtool in collection list

DEBUG: Processing compulab-uefi in collection list

DEBUG: Cache: default: Cache dir: /work/compulab-imx8p-som/build-som-imx8m-plus/tmp/cache/default-glibc/som-imx8m-plus/x86_64                                            | ETA:  --:--:--

DEBUG: Cache: default: Loading cache file: /work/compulab-imx8p-som/build-som-imx8m-plus/tmp/cache/default-glibc/som-imx8m-plus/x86_64/bb_cache.dat.d5021114211347c1ad3d82accec39130f2f35730b18c1697d72920eff1edd55d

Loading cache: 100% |#####################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:04

I am trying to work out if this is just an issue with my computer (and if my computer is just too slow) or
As an aside, if I reboot my computer, I return to the default state (where the files are all loaded from scratch).
I saw this question, which looks like the opposite, but has no clear answer:
Yocto dependency cache is not loaded
